# The opposite of enabling a person to do something

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english, antonyms

The title kind of says it all.

I'm looking for the opposite of "it enables the customer to perform …".
First thought was "it disables the customer to perform … " but that just doesn't sound right.

Looking at https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/disable but English not being my native language, I honestly have no idea what the most appropriate synonym would be.

Comment: Grab a thesaurus and open it up at *disable*. Start your hunt there.

Comment: Start by defining what you understand *enable* to mean. I have a specific word in mind for the opposite—but how I understand *enable* may be different from how you understand it.

Comment: I don't know what the most appropriate synonym would be either. Please provide an example of how you would use this word in context.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with simplicity and clarity: prevent.

"It prevents the client from"

It's also relatively natural language, but works in a technical context also: disallow may theoretically work, but sounds so stiff that its use is likely to impact readability.

Answer (score 0):

I think *disallow* would be appropriate here, meaning "does not allow" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disallow)

"it disallows the customer to perform …"

If you can change the wording of the rest of the sentence, then *prevents* would work, meaning "to keep from happening" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prevent)

"it prevents the customer from performing …"

Comment: Are you sure it's "disallows the customer to perform" and not "disallows the customer from performing"? The latter sounds better to me, but I haven't been able to find many usage examples either way.